# How to call xref-find-definitions without being prompted?

Tags: interactive, xref

Is it possible to call `xref-find-definitions` to find the definition at  the current point without being prompted to select the default?

I'd like to bind this to a key, so it immediately jumps to a definition. Currently it's prompting to select the default.

This command is prompting me for input every time:

```
(call-interactively 'xref-find-definitions)
```

Answer (score 2):

The question is unclear. What identifier do you want it to find the definition of?

By default it uses the identifier at point - and it doesn't prompt you.

If there's no identifier at point, it prompts you.

(To be more precise, it depends on the current command.  If `(xref--prompt-p this-command)` returns non-`nil` then it will also prompt you, even if there's an identifier at point.  But `(xref--prompt-p 'xref-find-definitions)` returns `nil`.)

If you're being prompted, and you think there's an identifier at point, then provide a step-by-step recipe to repro, starting from `emacs -Q` (no init file).

---

This is the sexp that's apparently prompting you:

```lisp
(xref--read-identifier "Find definitions of: ")
```

And this is the definition of that function:

```lisp
(defun xref--read-identifier (prompt)
  "Return the identifier at point or read it from the minibuffer."
  (let* ((backend (xref-find-backend))
         (id (xref-backend-identifier-at-point backend)))
    (cond ((or current-prefix-arg
               (not id)
               (xref--prompt-p this-command))
           (completing-read (if id
                                (format "%s (default %s): "
                                        (substring prompt 0 (string-match
                                                             "[ :]+\\'" prompt))
                                        id)
                              prompt)
                            (xref-backend-identifier-completion-table backend)
                            nil nil nil
                            'xref--read-identifier-history id))
          (t id))))
```

You can see that it shouldn't prompt, in the conditions I described.  You can also use `M-x debug-on-entry xref--read-identifier` to see exactly why it's prompting you, if it is.

Comment: Clarified, I want to find the thing at `(point)`

Comment: I was wrapping this command from my own lambda, causing `this-command` check to trigger the prompt. Using `(let ((xref-prompt-for-identifier nil)) ... )` resolves the issue, or setting `this-command` to the function being called.